# Prevent Excel to format string as date

Tags: excel, vba

I want to insert a string of type `10/3` in a cell like this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "10/3"
```

But Excel automatically formats the cell as a date or a number. I want to have it as a string.

How can I achieve this with VBA?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "10/3"
```

Comment: This works. Why? Because someone on the VBA language design team was drunk and thought it'd be funny; i'm sure of it.

Answer (score 7):

add a single quote `'` before the value - in your example, it would make the line

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "'10/3"
```

or, if you have a variable that holds the data

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "'" & MyValue
```