# Excel automatically changing to date format, even after correcting

Tags: excel, vba, format

I am helping to update someone else's VBA code since they got pulled to a different project. The code reads data from an input sheet, then unhides 4 results forms, populates them, saves them as a CSV file, then rehides them.

**The issue**: One of the data entries are numbers formatted as ##-#, like 20-2, 13-5, and 12-1. The 12-1 is the issue. Excel sees it and reads it as a date format and prints 1-Dec in my results sheet.

**Solutions I've tried**: I tried stopping the program before it rehides the data and changing the format but it throws off the numbers. And then I can't save it either, because the program has run halfway and I don't want to save the document like that. I then tried to unhide the sheets at the end after the program ran and cleared, but without completely removing the data after the program runs, it doesn't run correctly when you try to run it a second time. Lastly I tried unhiding before the program even ran and changed the format setting from "General" to "Text", but even after saving and closing it doesn't seem like that had an affect.

**My Question**: First of all am I changing the format right? And secondly does anyone know how to combat excel automatically formatting in this way. I have been working in VBA for about 3 weeks and have only encountered this once before but it fixed easily. This one doesn't seem to follow that pattern.

Comment: Check the "regional settings" in your windows system. Excel is following them.

Comment: Will do. What am I looking for? And what does the regional settings affect?

Comment: How to [Change the Windows regional settings to modify the appearance of some data types](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-the-windows-regional-settings-to-modify-the-appearance-of-some-data-types-edf41006-f6e2-4360-bc1b-30e9e8a54989)

Comment: Do you need to further operate with these "numbers"? If not, you can just change the data type to "text" and it will solve your issue.

Comment: Maybe adding the values like: "'" & YourValue will solve the issue?. If not and you are working on a sheet change:  Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = "@" and then add the value. Basically what @Rawrplus said :)

Comment: @Rawrplus this is in fact exactly what my coworker suggested: change the type or simply add a space to the front. I am going to try adding a space first. I am not familiar with the code to change format.

Comment: @JvdV is that the code you commented?^^

Comment: My apologies. I tried replying to both you and Rawrplus at the same time and it didn't let me and threw off the formatting. As I replied to them, I am not familiar with the code to change format; is that the line of code you commented?

Comment: @Matt Gaydon, this old post explains it further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574487/vba-excel-prevent-excel-to-format-string-as-date. But try to refrain from using ranges like "A1". That's why i used .Cells(1,1).

Comment: @JvdV Why should you refrain from using ranges?

Comment: @DirtyDeffy, a personal preference. I have less problems with larger pieces of code when I refer (dynamic rows and/or columns) to cells as ranges. So instead of  'refrain' I should have said it as a 'Tip' :)

Comment: @JvdV thanks for directing me to that link. Works perfectly!

Comment: @Rawrplus your suggestion works as well. There's another column that is printed to a new workbook and that method works perfectly in that case

Comment: @JvdV I see - I usually use it on table columns, in which case it's pretty easy to spot. But thanks for the input ;)

Comment: @DirtyDeffy Care to elaborate? It seems much easier to me refer to table columns using the `.ListColumns(<val>).Range/.DataBodyRange` method. Unless I missunderstood you. And @Matt, np, glad it helped :)

Comment: @Rawrplus I'm not sure i understand what you mean, but I'll try to elaborate what I meant. When I get to the point of changing formatting in my table I have usually already defined the last used row in the table via `.Cells.(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`. So i just change the formatting using ranges: `Range("A1:A" & LastRow).NumberFormat = "@"`. Using `.ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.NumberFormat = "@"` is just as easy, but a lot of my code uses the already defined `LastRow`, which is why I prefer to use it in this case as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was given an answer I thought I'd run my first self Q & A now, for those who may come upon this in the future. Credit to those users in the comments above for helping me figure this out. A code line like this:

```
Dim variable1 As Variant
variable1 = Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1").Value
Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("A1") = variable1
```

Or with the cells option, we'd see code like this:

```
Dim variable1 As Variant
variable1 = Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(1,1).Value
Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(1,1).NumberFormat = "@"
Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(1,1) = variable1
```

Both of these codes dimension a variable to store cell A1 in from Sheet 1, refer to sheet 2 and set that cell to a new format (making it format as a number as opposed to automatically formatting), then the last line sets that newly formatted cell equal to the value in the variable, but while retaining the new format we've set.